# Display markers in Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: vs-extensibility, vssdk

[image]

I need to display some markers in my Visual Studio extension (As in the image). I have gone through the VS SDK documentation and there are no references in this specific requirement. Is there any way to do this with current SDK? 
Thanks in advance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/visual-studio-sdk

Comment: This is not possible, you can only change the icon, and the source control state (in the space between the folder expand arrow and the icon). There is no way to custom draw nodes, as this tree view belongs to Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier for the quick repose, Can point me to references/examples on how to change the icon?

Comment: This is done through IVsUIHierarchy.GetProperty for the nodes you own, with VSHPROPID_IconXXX properties. If you don't own the node (not your project type), there is IVsUIHierarchy.SetProperty, but the owner may not support it. I'm not sure whether C# or VB project would like/support that.