# How to change project item icon programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Do you know how to change the c# file type icon marked bellow image(Startup.cs) temporary based on some condition for menu item click in VSIX extension development project.

I couldn't find any article in MSDN or somewhere regarding this.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hope this will be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427879/display-markers-in-visual-studio-solution-explorer?noredirect=1#comment81812984_47427879

Comment: @madufit1, Do you want to add a customer project file with an icon or just change the icon for the default project file? Reference:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a535a72a-8953-430a-84e6-5618e488f7c3/custom-file-type-icons-in-solution-explorer-part-3?forum=vsx, customer also asked different way to change the icon for custom project or default one, you could view it.

Comment: Need to change only one file icon at time, for menu item click, not all .cs files in the explore.